# Facebook Connect Button - page is multi-refresh

Tags: facebook

I would like to login to my website by facebook connect but I have problem with facebook connect BUTTON. When I click in this button, i'm login but then the page is multi-refresh.

This is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'xxxxxyyyxxxx',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
   window.top.location = 'http://mystite.pl/login.php?mode=fb_login';
 }
 });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

</script>
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, there is a page refresh after logging in to fb via js sdk (not 100% sure).

And you have there another refresh

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
       window.top.location = 'http://mystite.pl/login.php?mode=fb_login';
     }
 });
```

Comment: Yes, I know but how I can repair it?

Comment: I may have not expressed mayself properly. Remove this `FB.Event.sub...` refresh and reply, what happened.

Comment: Yep, try it. Still, you can get it back any time.

Comment: OK, but now I can't login on my page... When I click on fb login button, my page is refresh and i'm still logout :/
Where is problem? How I should configure this button? Where I should define a redirect URL where users are registering or logining (authorise url)?

Comment: Aren't you already logged in? If not, put that code back, for now, I am not able to help you any further.